User Getting Logged out when ever I reload page
I am building a nextjs 13 admin dashboard, I only have one issue that whenever user reloads the page it get redirected to login page, when inspect the developer mode, cookies is still present in Cookies section but Session Storage and locale storage is empty and on each login token changes
till now i don't have middleware implemented.
api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js
import {authOptions} from '@/lib/auth'
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next'

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export {handler as GET, handler as POST}

/lib/auth.js
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import { db } from "./db";
import { compare } from "bcryptjs";

export const authOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/sign-in",
  },
  rememberMe: {
    label: "Remember Me",
    type: "checkbox",
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "diven@gmail.com",
          validation: {
            required: true,
            pattern:
              /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/,
          },
        },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password", placeholder: "****" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) {
          return null;
        }

        const existingUser = await db.user.findUnique({
          where: { email: credentials?.email },
        });

        if (
          (existingUser &&
            existingUser.passwordExpirationDate &&
            existingUser.passwordExpirationDate < new Date()) ||
          (existingUser &&
            existingUser.verificationCodeExpiresAt &&
            existingUser.verificationCodeExpiresAt < new Date())
        ) {
          return null; // Trigger password reset
        }

        if (!existingUser) {
          return null;
        }
        const passwordMatch = await compare(
          credentials.password,
          existingUser.password
        );
        if (!passwordMatch) {
          return null;
        }

        const passwordAgeInDays = existingUser.lastPasswordResetDate
          ? Math.floor(
              (new Date().getTime() -
                existingUser.lastPasswordResetDate.getTime()) /
                (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
            )
          : 0;

        if (passwordAgeInDays > 30) {
          await db.user.update({
            where: { id: existingUser.id },
            data: { IsExpired: true },
          });
          return null;
        }
        const maxAge = credentials.rememberMe ? 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 : 60 * 60 * 24;
        return {
          id: `${existingUser.id}`,
          name: existingUser.name,
          username: existingUser.username,
          email: existingUser.email,
          role: existingUser.role,
          exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + maxAge,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {

      if (user) {
        return {
          ...token,
          id: user.id,
          username: user.username,
          role: user.role,
        };
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      const maxAge = token.exp - Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
      return {
        ...session,
        user: {
          ...session.user,
          id: token.id,
          username: token.username,
          role: token.role,
        },
        expires: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + maxAge,
      };
    },
  },
};


I want to keep user logged-in, and to manage user session

can you create a reusable codebase

@Yilmaz meaning, the auth.js is reusable, the error, I am facing it that if i reload the user gets logged out, or if I use redirect function which causes reload of a page then I am getting logged out

There may be issues with how the session is being managed or validated in your Next.js application using NextAuth. Before we apply some code do a fast check on two small but important details first.
a) Just to be sure, check your current configuration specifies JWT for session management. Make sure your .env file includes the NEXTAUTH_SECRET.
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=your_super_secret_value

b) Check that the client's clock is synchronized with the server's clock, as a significant time difference could lead to immediate token expiration issues.
If both ok then to ensure that users don't get redirected to the login page on refresh, you can implement a middleware in Next.js to check for session validity and redirect if the session is not valid. Create a file named _middleware.js in your pages directory and add the folloing code. This middleware checks if the user is authenticated before rendering any page and redirects to the login page if not authenticated.
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";

const secret = process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET;

export async function middleware(req) {
    const token = await getToken({ req, secret });

    const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;

    // Allow requests if the following is true...
    // 1. It's a request for next-auth session & provider fetching
    // 2. The token exists
    if (pathname.includes('/api/auth') || token) {
        return NextResponse.next();
    }

    // Redirect them to login if they are not logged in
    if (!token && pathname !== '/login') {
        const url = req.nextUrl.clone();
        url.pathname = '/login';
        return NextResponse.redirect(url);
    }
}

Then on client side you can also ensure that your application handles session status changes properly. Use the useSession hook from next-auth/react to manage session states. Example:
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react";

const MyComponent = () => {
    const { data: session, status } = useSession({
        required: true,
        onUnauthenticated() {
            // The user is not authenticated, push them to the login page
            signIn();
        }
    });

    if (status === "loading") {
        return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }

    return <p>Welcome {session.user.email}</p>;
};

